# Run a java function after a specific number of seconds

Tags: java, timer

I have a specific function that I want to be executed after 5 seconds.
How can I do that in Java?

I found javax.swing.timer, but I can't really understand how to use it. It looks like I'm looking for something way simpler then this class provides.

Please add a simple usage example.

Comment: Do you want to wait 5 seconds and then execute something or do you want to continue doing something else in the 5 seconds?

Comment: i want to continue doing something else

Answer (score 294, accepted):

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
        new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // your code here
            }
        }, 
        5000 
);
```

**EDIT:**

[javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) says:

> After the last live reference to a Timer object goes away and all outstanding tasks have completed execution, the timer's task execution thread terminates gracefully (and becomes subject to garbage collection). However, this can take arbitrarily long to occur.

Comment: If you run that code, you'll leak threads. Make sure to clean up the timer when you've finished.

Comment: @skaffman: I added a statement from the javadoc. Do you really have to clean up after calling schedule?

Comment: It might be OK, but then it might not be. If you run that code fragment multiple times, you'll have loose threads kicking about with no means of tidying them up.

Comment: `import java.util.Timer; import java.util.TimerTask;` might make it more obvious that this is not `javax.swing.Timer`. / Note, if you are using Swing (and actually AWT) you shouldn't be doing anything to change components on non-Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) threads (`java.util.Timer` tasks bad; `javax.swing.Timer` actions good).

Comment: @PaulAlexander According to the docs - calling timer's `cancel` method at the end of the run method would clear up the TimerTasks' execution thread.

Comment: 2021 here asking, do you still need to clear the thread manually?

Answer (score 76):

Something like this:

```
// When your program starts up
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

// then, when you want to schedule a task
Runnable task = ....    
executor.schedule(task, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// and finally, when your program wants to exit
executor.shutdown();
```

There are various other factory methods on `Executor` which you can use instead, if you want more threads in the pool.

And remember, it's important to shutdown the executor when you've finished. The `shutdown()` method will cleanly shut down the thread pool when the last task has completed, and will block until this happens. `shutdownNow()` will terminate the thread pool immediately.

Comment: `shutdown()` does not block. `awaitTermination()` does.

Comment: `shutdown()` just doesn't allow new tasks to be submitted. `shutdownNow()` also interrupts the tasks (not necessarily terminating immedietely).

Answer (score 33):

Example of using `javax.swing.Timer`

```
Timer timer = new Timer(3000, new ActionListener() {
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // Code to be executed
  }
});
timer.setRepeats(false); // Only execute once
timer.start(); // Go go go!
```

This code will only be executed once, and the execution happens in 3000 ms (3 seconds).

As camickr mentions, you should lookup "[How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)" for a short introduction.

Comment: Just that Go go go! :-)

Comment: worked like a charm! I think this is the most efficient way.

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 20):

As a variation of @tangens answer: if you can't wait for the garbage collector to clean up your thread, cancel the timer at the end of your run method.

```
Timer t = new java.util.Timer();
t.schedule( 
        new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // your code here
                // close the thread
                t.cancel();
            }
        }, 
        5000 
);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Timer t` be declared `final` since it's being accessed inside an inner class?

Comment: @JoshuaPinter Yes, it should be declared final but it does not need to be explicitly declared final in at least Java 8. It just needs to be "effectively final" (https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/03/what-is-effectively-final-variable-of.html)

Answer (score 9):

My code is as follows:

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule(

    new java.util.TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // your code here, and if you have to refresh UI put this code: 
           runOnUiThread(new   Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                            //your code

                        }
                   });
        }
    }, 
    5000 
);
```

Answer (score 7):

Your original question mentions the "Swing Timer". If in fact your question is related to SWing, then you should be using the Swing Timer and NOT the util.Timer.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on "[How to Use Timers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html)" for more information.

Answer (score 5):

you could use the Thread.Sleep() function

```
Thread.sleep(4000);
myfunction();
```

Your function will execute after 4 seconds. However this might pause the entire program...

Comment: And it only guarantees that the execution will run after 4sec, which could mean after 10 sec as well!

Comment: questzen, you'll find that *all* the methods here do that.  In fact, even if you're scheduling something at the OS level, you generally can only guarantee a minimum elapsed time before an event.

Comment: This is not what actual question was

Comment: I just had to give this a downvote - not at all an answer to the question at hand.

Comment: OP said in a comment "i want to continue doing something else"; this code obviously, doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

[`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) has this ability, but it's quite heavyweight.

[`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) also has this ability but opens several thread even if used only once.

Here's a simple implementation with a test (signature close to Android's [Handler.postDelayed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long))):

```
public class JavaUtil {
    public static void postDelayed(final Runnable runnable, final long delayMillis) {
        final long requested = System.currentTimeMillis();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // The while is just to ignore interruption.
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        long leftToSleep = requested + delayMillis - System.currentTimeMillis();
                        if (leftToSleep > 0) {
                            Thread.sleep(leftToSleep);
                        }
                        break;
                    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                    }
                }
                runnable.run();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void testRunsOnlyOnce() throws InterruptedException {
    long delay = 100;
    int num = 0;
    final AtomicInteger numAtomic = new AtomicInteger(num);
    JavaUtil.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            numAtomic.incrementAndGet();
        }
    }, delay);
    Assert.assertEquals(num, numAtomic.get());
    Thread.sleep(delay + 10);
    Assert.assertEquals(num + 1, numAtomic.get());
    Thread.sleep(delay * 2);
    Assert.assertEquals(num + 1, numAtomic.get());
}
```

Comment: it gives warning sleep called in a loop

Comment: The `while` is just to ignore interruption.

Answer (score 4):

All other unswers require to run your code inside a new thread. 
In some simple use cases you may just want to wait a bit and continue execution within the same thread/flow.

Code below demonstrates that technique. Keep in mind this is similar to what java.util.Timer does under the hood but more lightweight.

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class DelaySample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       DelayUtil d = new DelayUtil();
       System.out.println("started:"+ new Date());
       d.delay(500);
       System.out.println("half second after:"+ new Date());
       d.delay(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES); 
       System.out.println("1 minute after:"+ new Date());
    }
}
```

DelayUtil Implementation

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class DelayUtil {
    /** 
    *  Delays the current thread execution. 
    *  The thread loses ownership of any monitors. 
    *  Quits immediately if the thread is interrupted
    *  
    * @param duration the time duration in milliseconds
    */
   public void delay(final long durationInMillis) {
      delay(durationInMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
   }

   /** 
    * @param duration the time duration in the given {@code sourceUnit}
    * @param unit
    */
    public void delay(final long duration, final TimeUnit unit) {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long deadline = currentTime+unit.toMillis(duration);
        ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
        Condition waitCondition = lock.newCondition();

        while ((deadline-currentTime)>0) {
            try {
                lock.lockInterruptibly();    
                waitCondition.await(deadline-currentTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                return;
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
            currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static Timer t;

public synchronized void startPollingTimer() {
        if (t == null) {
            TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   //Do your work
                }
            };

            t = new Timer();
            t.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
```

is the best. When the Question is prevent Ui stack or a progress not visible before a heavy work or network call. We can use the following methods (from my experience) :

Run a method after one Second :

```
 public static void startMethodAfterOneSeconds(Runnable runnable) {
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                runnable.run();
            }

        });
        timer.setRepeats(false); // Only execute once
        timer.start(); 
    }
```

Run a method after n second once, Non repeating :

```
public static void startMethodAfterNMilliseconds(Runnable runnable, int milliSeconds) {
    Timer timer = new Timer(milliSeconds, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
            runnable.run();
        }

    });
    timer.setRepeats(false); // Only execute once
    timer.start(); 
}
```

Run a method after n seconds, and repeat :

```
 public static void repeatMethodAfterNMilliseconds(Runnable runnable, int milliSeconds) {
        Timer timer = new Timer(milliSeconds, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                runnable.run();
            }

        });
        timer.setRepeats(true); // Only execute once
        timer.start(); 
    }
```

And the Usage :

```
 startMethodAfterNMilliseconds(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // myMethod(); // Your method goes here. 
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the most transparent way is to use the *postDelayed* function of the *Handler* class the following way:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(this::function, 1000);
```

or you can implement the function inside, for example:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(() -> System.out.println("A second later"), 1000);
```

*Where the first argument is the function, the second argument is the delay time in milliseconds.
In the first example, the name of the called function is "function".*

Comment: Can you please update the answer with a sample program with appropriate import statements and also mention on which java version, it can run successfully.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).