# Call method after some delay in java

Tags: java, multithreading, delay

Scenario is like :

In my application, I opened one file, updated it and saved. Once the file saved event get fired and it will execute one method `abc()`.
But now, I want to add delay after save event get fired, say 1 minute. So I have added `Thread.sleep(60000)`. Now it execute the method `abc()` after 1 minute. Till now all works fine.

But suppose user saved file 3 times within 1 minute, the method get executed 3 times after each 1 minute. I want to execute method only one time in next 1 minute after first save called with latest file content.

How can I handle such scenario?

Comment: Use `ScheduledExecutorService`. Save the future returned from the `schedule` method and `cancel` it if there is another save action later on.

Comment: Duplicate of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258066/java-run-a-function-after-a-specific-number-of-seconds

Comment: not... not really a duplicate. OP ask for more features

Comment: is abc a static method?

Comment: yes it was but I changed it to non-static. The other guy gave answer and it worked but unfortunately he deleted his answer.

Comment: honestly: that was a bad solution. i'll edit my answer for you static method

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html)

create a member variable of type `Timer` in `YourClassType`

lets say: `private Timer timer = new Timer();`

and your method will look something like this:

```
public synchronized void abcCaller() {
    this.timer.cancel(); //this will cancel the current task. if there is no active task, nothing happens
    this.timer = new Timer();

    TimerTask action = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            YourClassType.abc(); //as you said in the comments: abc is a static method
        }

    };

    this.timer.schedule(action, 60000); //this starts the task
}
```

Comment: A single `Timer` instance would work; only the *tasks* need to be canceled and rescheduled.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Thread.sleep(), just have the static method change a static global variable to something that you can use to indicate blocking the method call?

```
public static boolean abcRunning;
public static void abc()
{
    if (YourClass.abcRunning == null || !YourClass.abcRunning)
    {
        YourClass.abcRunning = true;
        Thread.Sleep(60000);
        // TODO Your Stuff
        YourClass.abcRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Is there any reason this wouldn't work?