# How to schedule loop in Java

Tags: java, loops

I want to execute method to run every five minutes and want to release the resources. Can anybody explain how to schedule a loop so that I can execute loop every five minutes or so.

Thanks,

Comment: This could be answered in several ways. Could you provide more context? For example is this running in a container environment? Are you using any frameworks already (such as Spring)? Are there any other constraints?

Comment: You mean [like this](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)?

Comment: I think this may be usedfull for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18612656/call-method-after-some-delay-in-java
(Using Timer and TimerTask)

Comment: @Phil I'm not using any frameworks as such, since the project I'm working with is real-time one, so I want to release the resources used every five minutes or so. Actually it is OpenCV project where I want to remove the frames captured by camera periodically so that the application runs smoother. #OpenCV4Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
Timer timer = new Timer ();
TimerTask sometask = new TimerTask () {
    @Override
    public void run () {
        // code
    }
};

timer.schedule (sometask, 0l, 1000*60*5);
```

Comment: It looks good answer for my question. Let me put this this way, can I able release the resources after scheduling it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TimerTask`, and `Timer` to make schedule task, read about these [helper-link-1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/timer_schedule_period.htm), [helper-link-2](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/UsejavautilTimertoscheduleatasktoexecuteonce5secondshavepassed.htm)

Comment: Thanks man, your support appreciated. I'll check out those helper links.