# Is there a way to do a proper Thread.sleep in a @Scheduled(fixedDelay) block?

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to do a Thread.sleep within a @Scheduled(fixedDelay) block, but so far no luck. From what i read and saw, Thread.sleep doesn't work under @Scheduled.
I can think of a while loop but i don't feel that confident on that approach. Do you guys have any other suggestions ?

I'm running multiple tasks under this scheduler and I need to put some delays in between some of them. There is no question of splitting these tasks into multiple schedulers. Everything has to be done under the same one.

Thanks

Comment: Are there any condition for task after which thread should sleep? Maybe after N count of tasks?

Comment: There isn't a clear pattern on when those sleeps must be called. They have to be called based on the output of previous tasks under some circumstances . So it is random.

Comment: But when thread should wake up?

Comment: It might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31882624/thread-delay-using-scheduler-or-thread-sleep

Answer (score 0):

You can create atomic flag that will signal if thread should be slept.

```
private static final AtomicBoolean sleep = new AtomicBoolean(false);

@Scheduled(...)
public void schedule() {
    sleep.set(true);
}

public void process() {
    new Thread(() -> {
        while (true) {
            if (sleep.get()) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000L);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                sleep.set(false);
            }
            
            doSmth();
        }
    }).start();
}
```