# How to move data from one column to other in MySQL after every 24 hours using Java?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

There are 10 columns. After every 24 hours, data present in column10 should move to column9, column9 data should move to column8, so on and so forth.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: To be honest this sounds like an XY problem. What purpose are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There is probably a better way, like keeping some position ID in a column and data in other one...

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie Yes, I'm thinking to store a date value and select the previous 10 days' worth of data.

Comment: I think dropping the last column and renaming rest of columns would be better than moving data around.

Comment: @lc I think about the same, changing shema in production demonstrate a lack of analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You need to something like this and update the records:

```
 take a variable that counts the number of records

  num = select count(*) from <tablename>  
  for (i=num;i>num;num--) {
     Insert into <tablename> (columns name comma separated...) 
     values (select (same  columns comma separated...) 
     from <same tablename> where id=num) where id=num-1;
  }
```

and let me know, what about the first column.

Answer (score 0):

Just create another table with a different name and inserting the data for column's in whatever way you want.

```
    -- creating myTable
Create table myTable  (column1 int (11),column2 int (11),column3 int (11),column4 int (11),column5 int (11),
column6 int (11),column7 int (11),column8 int (11),column9 int (11),column10 int (11) );
insert into myTable values(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

    CREATE TABLE myTable_temp  (column1 int (11),column2 int (11),column3 int (11),column4 int (11),column5 int (11),
column6 int (11),column7 int (11),column8 int (11),column9 int (11),column10 int (11) );
insert into myTable_temp 
SELECT column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7,column8,column9,column10,column1
FROM 
    myTable ; 
    -- // Note: First create table then insert, "Create table select" will not work as required.
```

Then drop the original table and rename the _temp table to original table.

```
DROP TABLE tableName ;
RENAME table tableName_temp to tableName ;

select * from myTable ;
--  column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7 column8 column9 column10    
--  2         3       4        5        6       7       8       9       10      1
```

An for running the code After every 24 hours from JAVA you can use scheduler to call your
function in which your SQL code is written.

```
new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
        new java.util.TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // your SQL code here
            }
        }, 
        5000 
);
```

Or you can use the below link to see for more options.

[java: run a function after a specific number of seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258066/java-run-a-function-after-a-specific-number-of-seconds)