# Execute AsyncTask every three seconds

Tags: java, android

I built one AsyncTask class that returns a specific value. This value changes frequently, so, I need to call my AsyncTask class multiple times to show the value updated.

I'm getting on a different class the result from the AsyncTask.

```
     try {
        output = new task().execute(getconversationid).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And when the result from the AsyncTask updates, I call my other Class again to update everything.

```
     private void call() {

     new GetContacts().execute(id);

     }

    ...

    mobilemessages = contacts.length();

    ...

     myNum = Integer.parseInt(output);

     if(myNum != mobilemessages) {
         call();
     }
```

My question is how can i set a Timer or a Handler to update my class call(task) every three seconds?

Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't handle it this way. Why don't you just create a background thread that updates your value and then send it to a handler to update your UI when needed?

Comment: i didn't think about that, its so much easier, thanks

Comment: Here you go:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258066/java-run-a-function-after-a-specific-number-of-seconds

Comment: I would use `Observable.interval().map(i -> yourCall()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())subscribe(result -> doWhatYouHaveToDoWithIt());` (no asynctask at all)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Thread.sleep(3000);` 3000 is in milliseconds.

```
Try{

Thread.sleep(3000);

}catch(Exception ex){
}
```

Comment: unless combined with `publishProgress` (but then it would be recommended to run your asynctask on a dedicated executor, to avoid blocking all other asynctasks)