# How can I set one sensor to record data to a file every 10 milliseconds?

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, gyroscope, magnetometer

I develop an android app for my final year project. This app must collect sensor smartphone information from accelerometer, gyroscope and magnetometer and to save them into a file. So far I have done everything, but now I have some problem with sampling rate frequency of sensors, I do not exactly know how to deal with that.

I need a loop that will write to file every 10 milliseconds. I thought about a for loop but I don't know how to write the statement.

I expect to save information to file every 10 milliseconds.

Comment: Don't use a loop, use a Timer instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31268818/time-interval-in-java

Comment: Looks like at least the accelerometer sample rate won't be exactly what you request, so maybe you could just always remember the latest value from each sensor and write those to file in a `Runnable` which you run in a `Thread`. That would be one potential approach.

Comment: Thank you for answers. I am going to try to use what Markus recommended, it looks like he explained better than me what I am supposed to do.

Comment: handler = new Handler();

      
        runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.postDelayed(this, 10);
                // call functions here
            
            }
        };