# How to pause/sleep Java Program until a button click

Tags: java, javafx

I have created a Java Application which is a screen recorder. First I added functionality for Start and Stop recording but now asked to add PAUSE option too. I want to the entire working to stop when *Pause* is clicked and resume when clicked again. I am unable to use sleep because it requires time.

I have tried wait-notify logic. Can someone please guide me, how can I stop working of code until clicked again?

```
boolean paused;
    //boolean paused=false;
    @FXML
    private void pauseRec(ActionEvent event) throws AWTException, InterruptedException
    {
        if (paused==false)
        {
            paused= true;
            pauseRec.setText("Resume");
            recordStateLabel.setText("Recording Paused");
            synchronized(threadObject)
            {
                // Pause
                try 
                {
                    threadObject.wait();
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                }
            }
            //rob.delay(10000);
        }
        else if(paused ==true)
        {
            paused=false;
            pauseRec.setText("Pause");
            recordStateLabel.setText("Recording..");
            synchronized(threadObject)
            {
                threadObject.notify();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Invoking `Object#wait()` parks the _calling thread_.

Answer (score 0):

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), e -> System.out.println("Printed after 1 second from FX thread")));
timeline.play();
```

> So this will pause the current working for 1 sec duration and will
>   resume afterwards. For your case you can make this function to run for
>   finite time and then resume as the resume button is clicked.

[Follow this link for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49614806/10237845)

Comment: It can't find a constructor for KeyFrame which takes <duration,none> as parameters. (error)